# ZyXel Config SSH

Tags: ssh, firewall, putty

I got assigned to the task of creating a script to backup zywall configs.

I can connect to the firewall via putty-ssh client.
I looked at all the documentation, but I could not find a way to output the config file via the shell.

I wanted to have one of our servers connect to the firewall every day and put the echo off this command into a file as a backup.

Can you help me with displaying the config file in putty?

Comment: Which ZyWall make / model? Does it have to be via SSH? ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/ZYWALL_USG_200/cli_reference_guide/ZYWALL%20USG%20200_5.pdf for example says you can get that model to FTP its firmware and configuration files to an FTP server (section 38.7), which might be easier.

Comment: ZyWall USG 20. Thank you, man! I didn't know it was so easy. Just enabled the ftp in the web console and now I can see all the files - thank you! :DD
I'm shure the task of making powershell download files from an ftp server is not increadibly hard.